# Why xrandr ignores setting DPI in Zenbook of 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, laptop, asus, xrandr, dpi

I recently got a Zenbook Prime and installed ubuntu. Following The tips at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook worked out pretty well.

Only one problem remains: I cannot set the DPI.
I tried to do `xrandr --dpi 138/eDP1` but that doesn't seem to have the desired effect.
It changes the output of `xdpyinfo |grep resolution` but no change is visible.
Also, xrandr still reports the same screen size.

I tried adding `Xft.dpi: 138` to `.Xresources`, which didn't change anything.
I also tried to generate a `xorg.conf`, where I set in the monitor section

```
Option       "DPI" "138 x 138"
```

The `Xorg.0.log` then tells me

```
(==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
...
(WW) intel(0): Option "DPI" is not used
```

I know that it is possible to zoom fonts, but I'd rather actually set the DPI of the screen.

Hardware Zenbook Prime
Ubuntu: 12.10

Comment: Have you thought about accepting any answer? Have you found any answer yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you want, but as a workaround you can use Ubuntu Tweak's 'Font scaling' tweak to change the dpi of the fonts in your GUI, thus resizing a lot of elements and therefore having more screen real estate.

Comment: This is the workaround that I am currently using but it is not a real solution imho.

Comment: Andreas, did you find a solution. I am too trying to do the same.

Comment: @AndreasMueller Did you solve it? Trying same.

Comment: None, I did not :-/